# Submit input values which are not in form tag

Tags: jquery, submit

Hi
i'm using Jquery
and i have many input fileds but they are not in `<form>` tag
How can i submit the fields value?

It must bu simple submit not ajax

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the browser's submit and *not* use XHR, you'll need to wrap the input elements in a form and submit it.

```
$('#something :input')
 .wrapAll('<form action="somewhere.php" method="post" />')
 .submit();
```

Comment: `wrapAll()` returns the `$('#something :input')` object and not the wrapped form object. You might have to add a `parent()` between the `wrapAll()` and `submit()`